# Roth IRA Conversion

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

I contributed $5,500 to a non-deductible IRA on 12/27/2017 and next day initiated the conversion of the balance of $5,501.29 in non-deductible IRA to Roth IRA. Due to Brokerage Company processing delay, the Conversion of $5,501.29 to Roth IRA actually took place on 01/04/2018.

1. Is it a conversion to Roth for 2017 or 2018? How do I report this conversion 
   to IRS
2. Will I be able to convert another $5,500 from non-deductible IRA to Roth IRA 
   in 2018?
3. IS there any amount limit for Non-deductible IRA conversion to Roth IRA per 
   year?

Answer (score 5):

It’s a 2018 conversion. There is no conversion limit, so no real consequence of the timing here.

As long as you have no other IRA money, the tax due is pennies. No different than if the transfer occurred in 2017.

Members who read this should note that most brokers will request a week for these transactions. No consequence here, but if trying to convert a taxable sum, timing may matter.